# CTE for last non-null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table:

```
key  dat        value
KEY1 01.07.2019 3
KEY2 01.07.2019 null
KEY1 01.08.2019 null
KEY2 01.08.2019 4
KEY1 01.09.2019 null
KEY2 01.09.2019 5
```

I need to have the value have the last non-null value if there is no value for current month, resulting in this

```
key  dat        value
KEY1 01.07.2019 3
KEY2 01.07.2019 null
KEY1 01.08.2019 3 <=
KEY2 01.08.2019 4
KEY1 01.09.2019 3 <=
KEY2 01.09.2019 5
```

I could do it with cursor, but I believe the right way would be to go with CTE.

Answer (score 4):

The "correct" way is `lag(ignore nulls)`, but SQL Server does not implement that yet.

If the values are always increasing, you can use a cumulative max:

```
select t.*,
       max(value) over (partition by key order by date) as new_value
from t;
```

That is a special case, the rest of the answer provides more general answers.

Another method uses `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.value
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.key = t.key and t2.date <= t.date and t2.value is not null
      order by t2.date desc
     ) t2
```

And a third method uses two levels of window functions:

```
select t.*, max(value) over (partition by key, not_null_date)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when value is not null then date end) over (partition by key order by date) as not_null_date
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: values are NOT always increasing, sometimes they go down. Would 2nd and 3rd method work?

Comment: @Mara . . . Yes, they will.  I have clarified.